# LISP length of the longest sublist

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I want to generate the length of the longest sublist. For example, for the list `(1 (2 (3 (4 5)) (6 7) 8) 9)` , the result would be 4, because of the sublist `(2 (3 (4 5)) (6 7) 8)`, which has 4 as the length.

I have tried to do this:

```
(defun len(l)
    (cond
         ((null l) 0)
         ((atom l) 1)
         (t (+ (len(cdr l)) 1))
    )
)
(defun lun(l)
    (cond
        ((atom l) 1)
        (t(apply #'max (mapcar #' len l)))
    )   
)
```

For the example above, it returns 4, but the problem is that it analyses just the first level of the sublist. If i try to resolve it for the list `(1 (2 (3 (4 5 a a a a)) (6 7) 8) 9)` it also returns 4, even though it should be 6 because of the list `(4 5 a a a a)`, it still only takes the list `(2 (3 (4 5 a a a a)) (6 7) 8)`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Lisp has a built-in `LENGTH` function, you don't need to write your own, except to handle the case of atoms.

Comment: The `lun` function doesn't recurse into nested lists, it just processes the top-level list with `mapcar`.

Comment: And how can I have access to the nested lists too?

Comment: LIke I said, you need to do call the function recursively. Put the longest list in the top-level list in a variable. Then call `lun` on each of the sublists; if it returns a list that's longer than the variable, replace the variable with it. Finally, return the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inputs are list of lists of lists (etc.), also known as trees.
You want to compute the longest length of one of the lists that makes a tree. Roughly speaking, you need to iterate over subtrees, compute their respective longest length, and combine those length into a new, maximal length.

A first sketch of the function is as follows, based on the LOOP macro (you still need a bit of work to convert it to a fully recursive solution):

```
(defun longest-length (tree)
  (loop for subtree in tree maximize (longest-length subtree)))
```

Just as explained above, you divide your problems into subproblems, solve them recursively by finding
for each subtree their longest length, and combine them by returning the
maximum of each local maximum.

But the above is missing a couple of things. First, you need to take into account that the tree's length itself should be computed:

```
(defun longest-length (tree)
  (max (length tree)
       (loop for subtree in tree maximize (longest-length subtree))))
```

Also, the code fails when it reaches items that are not cons-cells.
You now have to add code for the base case where trees are not cons-cells. In particular, nil is treated as an empty lists and not as a symbol:

```
(defun longest-length (tree)
  (typecase tree
    (cons (max (length tree)
               (loop
                 for subtree in tree
                 maximize (longest-length subtree))))
    (null 0)
    (t 1)))
```

Here is a test:

```
CL-USER> (longest-length '(1 (2 (3 (4 5 a a a a)) (6 7) 8) 9))
6
```

Consider also using `reduce`, which unlike `apply` introduces no  restrictions on the number of elements in the list (`call-argument-limit`):

```
(reduce #'max (mapcar ... tree) :initial-value (length tree))
```

Comment: May I ask you for an explanation with map functions please?